# Heroku postgres database changes don't show up in production app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

I'm taking over a project in which the bulk of the backend has already been written in Ruby (I'm completely new to Ruby). We're using Heroku to host our backend with a postgres database. I've tried using pg:psql to make changes to the database manually for a couple of exceptional scenarios. Unfortunately the data on the app doesn't seem to reflect the data that I see in the database. I've tried to use the pg:push command to commit the changes, but I don't have a local database to push. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the rails console and updating the records with ActiveRecord. For example, you could do:

```
heroku run rails console --remote <remote>
user = User.first
user.update!(first_name: "Sankalp")
```

If the records update fine, then you might have an issue with your database. Confirm that you're connecting to the right database by going into Heroku settings and checking the DB_URL.

Answer (score 0):

Make migration files to change anything in database and push to heroku.

Then run migrations using command:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

If you want to add some data on db, then create record in seed.rb file and run it on heroku by command:

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Open heroku console and check tables and data manully. Command:

```
heroku run rails console
User.all
```